# Pattern test for string ending in Python

Tags: python, string, design-patterns, conditional-statements

In Python, how to make a pattern test for a string ending. So just something like:

```
"name.txt"=="*.txt"
```

I tried to use the re library:

```
pattern = re.compile("*.txt")
pattern.match("somename.txt")
```

But the obvious seems not to work. Could someone paste his code? Please no link to the re libray reference. For today I am messed up with that. Thank you guys!

Comment: `"name.txt".endswith('.txt')` for simple suffixes. `'*.txt'` isn't valid, `'*'` is the repitition operator. And `'.'` matches any character. Anchoring is your friend for end-of-line: `r'.*\.txt$'`. But yeah, just use `fnmatch()`.

Comment: That's not a regex pattern. The module you're looking for is [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fnmatch.html).

Comment: @dhke a patterns starting with `*` isn't valid at all.

Comment: @AlexHall ... and that, too. Fixed.

Comment: cool, ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `endswith` to check if a string ends with a specified text.

```
filename = "name.txt"
pattern = ".txt"

print filename.endswith(pattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for your learning, if you wanted to go about searching for a file extension using regex you could do the following, which pattern searches at the end of a provided string (the \Z specifies matching at the end):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(".txt\Z")

if pattern.search('name.txt'):
    print "Match"
else:
    print "No match"
```

Comment: And what I learned here too, is that a pattern evaluating True in the if function, despitly prints weird output if evaluated directly. Evaluating pattern.search('name.txt') directly gives:
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(4, 8), match='.txt'>

Answer (score 0):

you can just make a simple test as :

```
>>> file="name.txt"
>>> pattern=".txt"
>>> pattern in file
True
```